# unable to access array

Tags: javascript, react-native, multidimensional-array, setstate

here's my state:

```
state={show: false,addDisplay:true,key:'',sections: [{title:'primary',
                                                         data:['a','b']
                                                      }]
        }
```

and here I'm trying to setState:

```
this.setState({...this.state,sections: [{title:'primary',
                                      data: [...this.state.sections.data,this.state.input]
                                       }]
             })
```

why is this.state.sections.data undefined?

Comment: Because `this.state.sections` is an array, you aren't accessing it like it's an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.state.sections is an array, try with 
`...this.state.sections[0].data`